# Which brands (fictional and non-fictional) have appeared in the Town/City theme?

Tags: city, theme

A few years ago I wrote an [article](http://www.frankieroberto.com/weblog/708) about the fictional organisation logos found in the City theme.

I'd quite like to revisit this, as I'm sure I must have missed some. I also only focused on the fictional brands, but I know some licensed brands have appeared too.

My current list is:

**Fictional**

- Police
- Fire
- Hospital (Star of Life logo)
- Postal service (envelope and bugle icon)
- Railway (double arrow logo)
- Refuse / recycling agency (eg [4206](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4206-2))
- Highway maintenance agency (motorway icon) - eg [6653](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6653-1) and [6521](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6521-1))
- 'Octan' (oil/energy company)
- 'AirLine' (now uses the bird logo)
- 'International Transport' (eg [161](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=161-1) and [6367](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6367-1))
- Cargo company (yellow box on blue world logo) - eg [4551](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4555-1)

**Real**

- Shell (1966-1980, before Octan was introduced, e.g. [1256](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1256-1))
- Ferrari (eg [8673](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=8673-1) - part of the 'Racers' theme but minifig scale)
- Toys R Us ([7848](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7848-1))
- Maersk ([1552](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1552-1), [1831](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1831-1), [1651](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1651-2), etc)
- Deutsche Bahn (eg [7735](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7735-1))
- BNSF (Burlington North Sante Fe) eg [10133](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10133-1)
- Lego (eg [4549](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4549-1) and [10156](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10156-1))
- Exxon (eg [6679](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6679-2) [6375](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6375-2))
- Danone (only once - [1591](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1591-1))
- [Color Line](http://www.colorline.com/) - eg [2149](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=2149-1)

Are there any others?

Comment: I suppose NASA would be on the outskirts of the Town/City theme, but there it is...

Answer (score 7):

I can't believe that nobody else else has posted the most important *real* company that appears within the LEGO City theme... the LEGO company itself!

---

There is a good [list of promotional sets on Brickipedia](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_promotional_sets), that includes the set theme. Many of the town / city sets include logos or brand names of real-world companies.

Other sets that include real-world brands (some of which don't count as Town / City, according to the [Brikipedia themes list](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/List_of_themes)) include:

- Esso appeared on [some very early sets](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/Esso).
- DB (Deutsche Bahn) appears on various trains, including [7725](http://lego.wikia.com/wiki/7725_Electric_Passenger_Train_Set).
- Sports sets such as, [3432](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3432-1) which has NBA logos on the player's chests, or [65221](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=65221-1) that included a Spalding basketball.
- [1656](http://www.peeron.com/inv/sets/1656-2) Viking Line cruise ship.
- [Interfrigo](http://www.interfrigo.com/), set [147](http://www.toysperiod.com/lego-set-reference/train/4.5v/lego-147-refrigerated-car-with-forklift/).

Comment: Of course! How did I miss that? Set 10156 seems like the most recent example I can find, but I'm sure there are others. I've added it to the list in the question.

Comment: Didn't think about LEGO either, I guess it was too right under our noses.

Comment: I have a very old set with the word "Legoland" printed on a Brick. So that's another

Answer (score 5):

Here are some additional non-fictional brands and their set(s) under the Town theme:

**Chocomel (Nutricia), Holland**

[Chocolate Factory](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1620-2)

**Canada Post**

[Mail Van](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=105-1)

[Mail Truck](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=107-2)

**ANWB (Breakdown service), Holland**

[Breakdown Assistance](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1590-2)

[Roadside Recovery Van and Tow Truck](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=2140-1)

**UNICEF**

[UNICEF Van](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=106-1)

**Touring Club Schweiz**

[Breakdown Assistance](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1589-2)

**Air Canada**

[Air Canada Jet Plane](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=611-2)

**MD Foods (Denmark)**

[Milk Truck](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1952-1)

**Emirates**

[Emirates Airliner](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1973-1)

**Arla (milk supply company, Sweden)**

[Milk Delivery Truck](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1581-2)

**Renault**

[Racing Car](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1750-1)

**Velux**

[House with Roof-Windows](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1854-1)

**Color Line**

[Container Lorry](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=2149-1)

**Tine Dairies (Norway)**

[Milk Delivery Truck](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1029-1)

**McDonalds**

[McDonalds Restaurant](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=3438-1)

Also there is the ['Houses' set](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1484-1) from Weetabix. This doesn't actually include the brand in the Town set itself, but includes the pieces to build a Weetabix figure in the set and is part of the Town theme.

Under the City theme:

**Vestas**

[Vestas Wind Turbine](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4999-1)

Answer (score 2):

Real brands include:

Mostly it's the three early Maersk Trucks - [1552](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1552-1), [1831](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1831-1) and [1651](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=1651-2) that are usually listed under the Town theme.

[Toys R Us](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=7848-1) also appeared on one City themed truck

Outside of the Town/City themes but still minifig scale you then have:

- [Maersk Train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10219-1) - under Trains.
- SNCF - In it's old orange livery is the basis for the [Horizon Express train](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=10233-1) under Creator.
- Ferrari - Is usually listed under the "[Racers](http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=Racers&query=ferrari)" theme rather than Town/City
- Porsche - In the 2015 LEGO Speed Champions line
- McLaren - In the 2015 LEGO Speed Champions line

Other brands have also appeared in other more advanced/non-minifig scale themes, such as:

- Boing - The [787 Dreamliner](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10177-1).
- Maersk (again) - The [Sealand Container Ship](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10152-1)
- Sopwith Aviation - The [Sopwith Camel](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10226-1).
- Volkswagen - The [T1 Camper](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10220-1) and [Beetle](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=10187-1)

Comment: Don't you mean SNCF?

Comment: I don't think any of these have been in town/city themes

Comment: Thanks, I've updated the question to add Maersk to the list, and also to note that Ferrari wasn't technically part of City (though I've kept it in as it's clearly compatible).

Comment: The Horizon Express is clearly inspired by the SNCF early TGRs, but as it isn't actually identified as such I've left it off the list.

Answer (score 2):

I wouldn't consider "hospital" as fictional.

At first, LEGO did seem to use the [Red Cross logo](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=6688-1), but they have since then had to stop (presumably because of the Red Cross being very protective about their logo). Note that [the logo they have been using since](http://www.brickset.com/detail/?Set=4431-1) isn't [fictional either](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_of_Life).

12v era trains provided [stickers for a lot of different train companies](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=7740stk01), I'm not sure if what they use now is fictionnal or not (I think so)

Comment: You're right about the 'Star of Life' not being entirely fictional. Although it's also not solely owned as an identity of any particular real-world organisation as I understand it, so it's arguably more of a generic symbol. Oh and I'd forgotten about the early Red Cross bricks!

Comment: Those 12V train stickers are interesting - they definitely include some real world companies (including British Rail and the Danish State Railways). Were any of those ever produced as printed bricks, I wonder?

Answer (score 2):

Lego also collaborated with several airline companies to release a standard plane but with stickers denoting the airline name. I remember excitedly purchasing them back in the day. They were only available through their in-flight shopping if I recall correctly. I have two. One is El-Al and the other one is for a Japanese carrier (need to check either ANA or Japan Airlines).
Here is the link to the "generic set" although it is labelled El-Al.
http://www.brickset.com/detail/?set=4032-3

You can actually see the whole set of airlines here:
http://www.brickset.com/browse/themes/?theme=World%20City

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how you classify "Town/City", you might want to consider these:

**Real**

- Mini Cooper [big](http://brickset.com/sets/10242-1/Mini-Cooper-MK-VII), [small](http://brickset.com/sets/40109-1/MINI-Cooper-Mini-Model)
- Nasa [(several parts)](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?q=nasa)

**Fictional**

- Ghostbusters [21108](http://brickset.com/sets/21108-1/Ghostbusters-Ecto-1)
- Gringotts and other Harry Potter brands [4714](http://brickset.com/sets/4714-1/Gringott-s-bank), [10127](http://brickset.com/sets/10217-1/Diagon-Alley)
- The smiling minifig coffee cup [part](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItem.asp?P=15496pb01)